# Сворачивание приложения в трей

Tags: c#, wpf

Допустим есть программа которая фоном делает определенные операции, не важно какие, допустим каждые 10 секунд собирает информацию по нагрузке ЦП и RAM. Программа сама по себе десктопная, запускается ручками, надо бы сделать ее чтобы она в авторане запускалась.

Вопрос: как научить ее чтобы при сворачивании она скрывалась в трей, и при необходимости опрокидывала какие либо сообщения. Например как антивирус касперского. Висит в трее, опрокидывает уведомления, когда открываешь - появляется в панеле задач

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Я использую [`Hardcodet.NotifyIcon.Wpf`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Hardcodet.NotifyIcon.Wpf/)

В XAML добавьте пространство имен: `xmlns:tb="http://www.hardcodet.net/taskbar"`

В контейнер окна поместите:

```
<tb:TaskbarIcon Visibility="Visible"
                ToolTipText="..." IconSource="..."/>
```

Для того чтобы свернуть окно в трей, подпишитесь на событие `StateChanged`:

```
WindowState prevState;

private void Window_StateChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (WindowState == WindowState.Minimized)
        Hide();
    else
        prevState = WindowState;
}
```

Чтобы развернуть, например при левом клике по иконке в трее:

```
private void TaskbarIcon_TrayLeftMouseDown(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Show();
    WindowState = prevState;
}
```

Для отображения каких-либо сообщений, можно использовать, например, `Popup` или `ToolTip`

Comment: а где бинд на левый клик. при левом клике по иконке в трее ничего не происходит !

Comment: @Андрей, ну вроде никто такого не просил. Если вы не знаете как это сделать – задайте отдельным вопросом.

Comment: Ну или просто добавьте здесь комментарием, если я чего упустил. В любом случае – этот ответ не готовое на 100% решение всех проблем, а только набросок того как можно это сделать. Ну и подписываться на событие не обязательно в XAML.

Comment: <tb:TaskbarIcon Visibility="Visible"
                ToolTipText="..." IconSource="..." TrayLeftMouseDown="TaskbarIcon_TrayLeftMouseDown"/>

Comment: Вот так должно быть )