# Проблема с закрытием окна

Tags: c#, wpf

В приложении есть notifyIcon с contextmenu на нем, в нем пункты Свернуть и Выход.

На закрытие окна есть функция сворачивания в трей если в настройках выбрано "Сворачивать при закрытии". Проблема в том, что при выборе Выход ( -> `closeApp()` ) в контекстном меню срабатывает `Window_Closing` и не дает закрыть окно:

```
private void hideform(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     this.Visibility =  Visibility.Hidden;
}

private void Window_Closing(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
{
    if (Properties.Settings.Default.minonclose == "True")
    {
        e.Cancel = true;
        this.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;

    }
    else
    {
        this.Close();
        notifyicon.Icon = null;
        notifyicon.Dispose();
    }
}

private void closeApp(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Close();
}
```

Пробовал вариант с установкой глобального флага `bool forceClose`:

```
private void closeApp(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    forceClose = true;
    this.Close();
}

private void Window_Closing(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
{
    if (forceClose == true)
    {
        this.Close();
        notifyicon.Icon = null;
        notifyicon.Dispose();
    }
    else
    {
        if (Properties.Settings.Default.minonclose == "True")
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
            this.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
        }
        else
        {
            this.Close();
            notifyicon.Icon = null;
            notifyicon.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

Но приложение завершается с ошибкой:

> Необрабатываемое исключение в компоненте приложения. Во время закрытия
>   окна нельзя установить для `Visibility`  значение `Visible` или
>   вызвать `Show`, `ShowDialog`, `Close` или
>   `WindowInteropHelper.EnsureHandle`

Comment: можно попробовать просто убить все  Environment.Exit(0); Хотя мне кажется это Вас не устроит

Answer (score 0, accepted):

сделал так:

```
private void closeApp(object sender, EventArgs    
{
    forceClose = true;
    this.Close();
    notifyicon.Icon = null;
    notifyicon.Dispose();
}

private void Window_Closing(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
{
    if (forceClose == false)
        {
            if (Properties.Settings.Default.minonclose == "True")
            {
                e.Cancel = true;
                this.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
            }
            else
            {
                e.Cancel = false;
                notifyicon.Icon = null;
                notifyicon.Dispose();
            }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Проблема в том, что у вас окно дважды закрывается и второй раз кидается исключение. Надо так:

```
    private void closeApp(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // все закрываем
        forceClose = true;
        this.Close();
        notifyicon.Icon = null;
        notifyicon.Dispose();
    }

    private void Window_Closing(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        if (forceClose != true)
        {
           // тут еще надо проверить, когда вообще этот кусок кода вызывается
           {
            if (Properties.Settings.Default.minonclose == "True")
            {
                e.Cancel = true;
                this.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
            }
            else {
                this.Close();
                notifyicon.Icon = null;
                notifyicon.Dispose();
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: у вас тоже лишняя команда `this.Close();` в `Window_Closing`

Comment: да, думаю, что ветка else вообще не нужна, она из исходного кода

Answer (score 1):

Слишком у вас заморочено как-то.

Я использую `Hardcodet.NotifyIcon.Wpf` (как [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/687887/218063))

В разметке окна добавлено пространство имен `xmlns:tb="http://www.hardcodet.net/taskbar"` и в корневой Grid добавлено:

```
<tb:TaskbarIcon Visibility="Visible" TrayLeftMouseUp="TaskbarIcon_TrayLeftMouseUp">
    <tb:TaskbarIcon.ContextMenu>
        <ContextMenu>
            <MenuItem Header="Свернуть" Click="MenuItem1_Click"/>
            <MenuItem Header="Закрыть" Click="MenuItem2_Click"/>
        </ContextMenu>
    </tb:TaskbarIcon.ContextMenu>
</tb:TaskbarIcon>
```

Код окна:

```
public bool HideOnClose { get; set; }
bool forceClose = false;

public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

private void MenuItem1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Hide();
}

private void MenuItem2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    forceClose = true;
    Close();
}

private void Window_Closing(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
{
    if (!forceClose && HideOnClose)
    {
        e.Cancel = true;
        Hide();
    }
}

private void TaskbarIcon_TrayLeftMouseUp(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Show();
}
```

В обработчике `Window_Closing` дополнительно вызывать `Close()` не нужно, достаточно установить `e.Cancel` в `true` если закрывать не нужно и в `false` если нужно, `false` как раз установлено по умолчанию.