# Как отобразить WPF контрол на панели задач Windows?

Tags: c#, wpf

Есть приложение на WPF и появилась необходимость в подобного рода "виджете" на панели задач, как на скринах ниже.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

*Zune software*

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

*Windows Media Player*

К сожалению в WPF отсутствует функционал для работы с панелью задач как таковой. Полагаю что имеются какие-нибудь функции в WinAPI для решения подобных задач. Однако это все спрятано в каких то неведомых мне дебрях, либо просто я плохо искал/гуглил. Может кто сталкивался уже с такой проблемой?

Comment: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17484978/5045688), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17667988/5045688), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18327185/5045688).

Comment: Это назвается [Desk Bands](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144099.aspx#desk_bands). Есть [либа](https://github.com/dsafa/CSDeskBand). Еще посмотрите [это](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13889290/how-do-i-place-my-custom-toolbar-deskband-on-taskbar-in-windows-7-win-wpf)

Comment: целый цикл статкй про таскбар [WINDOWS 7 - ПАНЕЛЬ ЗАДАЧ](https://blog.zwezdin.com/tag/win7-taskbar/)

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Сворачивание приложения в трей](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/687880/%d0%a1%d0%b2%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b2-%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b9)